# Date conversion error on UPDATE command

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a stored procedure that is throwing an error on an UPDATE command here are the pertinent lines of code.

```
DECLARE @submitDate1 DATETIME;
SET @submitDate1 = GETDATE()

   SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @currTable + ' SET [lang_String] = ''' + @lang_String + ''', [date_Changed] = ''' +  @submitDate1 + ''', [prev_LangString] = ''' + @prev_LangString + ''', [needsTranslation] = ''' + @needsTranslation + ''' WHERE [ID] = ' + CAST(@ID as nvarchar(10)) + '; '
   EXEC(@sql)
```

Here is the error...
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I hope that no one fills in @lang_String with `' WHERE 1=0; DROP TABLE Users;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert the date into a string before concatenating it to the other strings:

```
... = ''' +  convert(varchar(20), @submitDate1) + ''', [...
```

Comment: Why though, I am curious, the field is defined in the destination table as DATETIME.

Comment: @marc11h: Because you are creating a string. It's not related to the table at all, until you use the string as a query.

Comment: @Marc11h You are building a dynamic varchar. You can't concatenate varchar with datetime without converting or casting the datetime

Comment: Thank you, my thought was that the DECLARE statement defined the type. No varchar invloved in typing the variable. Tough to understand this sort of ilogical naming.

Comment: Because `@sql` is, presumably, a VARCHAR().  And if you want to store the date in your @sql string, you need to store it as a string...  (The fact that you later execute it, so as to put a DATETIME value into a DATETIME field, has nothing to do with creating the @sql string int he first place.)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
convert(varchar,@submitDate1)
```

at the place where you have used `@submitDate1` variable.

SQL does not do implicit conversion from date to string!